# Loop through nested array in Twig

Tags: theming, 8

I have created a variable to use in my twig template. The variable consists of a nested array. If I dump the variable I get the following result:

```
dump(gallery_images)
array (size=2)
  'img' => 
    array (size=15)
      0 => 'path-to-file.jpeg'
      1 => 'path-to-file.jpeg'
      .....
   'alt' =>
    array (size=15)
      0 => 'img 1 alt text'
      1 => 'img 2 alt text'
```

I want to loop through gallery_images and map the alt text to the image. My loop was working fine before I added the nested array / alt text. This is how I expected it to work:

```
{% for gallery_image in gallery_images %}
  <li>
      <img src="{{ gallery_image.img }}" alt="{{ gallery_image.alt }}" />
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

That did not work, then I tried to call the src and alt with

```
{{ gallery_image.0 }}
{{ gallery_image.1 }}
```

Then I only got 1 file and 1 alt text. What is the correct way to loop through the nested array? Also bear in mind I may want to add title text next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have control over your array structure?

Why not just change it to this:

```
[
  0 => ['alt' => 'alt text', 'img' => 'image-path'],
  1 => ...?
]
```

Because then your logic would work, but right now you have the reversed structure. What you could do is loop over the image paths with `{% for key, path in gallery_images.img %} and use the key to`access gallery_iamges.alt[key]` (not 100% sure about the exact syntax). Certainly more complicated that way.

Comment: Yes I do have control because I am creating the array in the .theme file, so I will try that. Thanks.